# Find an arithmetic progression that $a_{5}a_{7}-a_{4}a_{9}=60$ , $a_{11}=25$ and $m$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^{m} a_{k}=195$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $\{a_{n}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of real numbers that $a_{k+1}-a_{k}=d$, for any $k\in\mathbb{N}$

If, $a_{5}a_{7}-a_{4}a_{9}=60$ and $a_{11}=25$

And also  $d\in\mathbb{N}$

Find $m\in \mathbb{N}$ that:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{m} a_{k}=195$$

Answer (score 2):

I think I got it:

First:

$a_n=a_m+(n-m)d$

then

$a_5=a_{11}+(5-11)d=25-6d$

$a_7=a_{11}+(7-11)d=25-4d$

$a_4=a_{11}+(4-11)d=25-7d$

$a_9=a_{11}+(9-11)d=25-2d$

$60=(25-6d)(25-4d)-(25-7d)(25-2d)=25d^2-10d$

then: $2d^2-5d-12=0$, so $d=4$ or $d=-\frac{3}{2}$

$a_k=a_{11}+(k-11)d=4k-19$

$\sum_{1}^{m}4k-19=2m(m+1)-19m=2m^2-17m=195$

$2m^2-17m-195=0$ then $m=15$ or $m=-\frac{13}{2}$

Comment: Perfectly right. I was also typing the same stuff.

Comment: Why $a_n=a_m+(n-m)d$?

Comment: @MonsieurGalois   Since $a_{n}=a_{1}+(n-1)d$, then$a_{m}=a_{1}+(m-1)d$ and
$a_n -a_m=(n-1)d-(m-1)d=(n-m)d$

Comment: Oh, now I understand, thanks :-). Nice proof.